# Selected Feature how to zoom in ArcMap viewer window

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

I will selected one feature in ArcMap that feature zoom in viewer window in ArcMap i tried in ArcMap VBA but no result

```
Public Sub zoomtool()

Dim pDoc As IMxDocument
Set pDoc = ThisDocument
Dim pMap As IMap
Set pMap = pDoc.FocusMap
```

-----------------------------------------------Here how to call viewer window

[image]

```
Set act = pMap

Dim pLayer As IFeatureLayer
Dim pFSel As IFeatureSelection
For i = 0 To pMap.LayerCount - 1

Set pLayer = pMap.Layer(i)
Set pFSel = pLayer

'Get the selected features
Dim pSelSet As ISelectionSet
Set pSelSet = pFSel.SelectionSet

Dim pEnumGeom As IEnumGeometry
Dim pEnumGeomBind As IEnumGeometryBind

Set pEnumGeom = New EnumFeatureGeometry
Set pEnumGeomBind = pEnumGeom
pEnumGeomBind.BindGeometrySource Nothing, pSelSet

Dim pGeomFactory As IGeometryFactory
Set pGeomFactory = New GeometryEnvironment

Dim pGeom As IGeometry
Set pGeom = pGeomFactory.CreateGeometryFromEnumerator(pEnumGeom)

pDoc.ActiveView.Extent = pGeom.Envelope
pDoc.ActiveView.Refresh
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided zooms the main view to the selected features, but also continues even trying to zoom layers with no selection.. first test for selection using [ISelectionSet.Count](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Count_Property/002500000807000000/) before trying to zoom; After zooming to the selected feature you need to exit the loop so you don't go trying to zoom to *every* layer - use [Exit For](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414969/excel-vba-exit-for-loop).

```
Public Sub zoomtool()

    Dim pDoc As IMxDocument
    Set pDoc = ThisDocument
    Dim pMap As IMap
    Set pMap = pDoc.FocusMap
    Set act = pMap

    Dim pLayer As IFeatureLayer
    Dim pFSel As IFeatureSelection
    For i = 0 To pMap.LayerCount - 1

        Set pLayer = pMap.Layer(i)
        Set pFSel = pLayer

        'Get the selected features
        Dim pSelSet As ISelectionSet
        Set pSelSet = pFSel.SelectionSet
        ' check there is anything selected for this layer
        If pSelSet.Count > 0 then

            Dim pEnumGeom As IEnumGeometry
            Dim pEnumGeomBind As IEnumGeometryBind

            Set pEnumGeom = New EnumFeatureGeometry
            Set pEnumGeomBind = pEnumGeom
            pEnumGeomBind.BindGeometrySource Nothing, pSelSet

            Dim pGeomFactory As IGeometryFactory
            Set pGeomFactory = New GeometryEnvironment

            Dim pGeom As IGeometry
            Set pGeom = pGeomFactory.CreateGeometryFromEnumerator(pEnumGeom)

            pDoc.ActiveView.Extent = pGeom.Envelope
            pDoc.ActiveView.Refresh
            Exit For ' escape out now that the zoom is refreshed
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

However you were talking about a viewer window, these are a little more complex. You can access the windows of the application using [IApplicationWindows.DataWindows](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v00000034000000) (IApplication implements IApplicationWindows), this returns all sorts of windows: Overview, magnifier, table views... Use the TypeOf() to decide if you've found the window you're after (`TypeOf(window) = IMapInsetWindow`), after you've got that far you need to set the [VisibleBounds](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000008tz000000) of the MapInset:

```
Dim pLayer As IFeatureLayer
Dim pFSel As IFeatureSelection
Dim pAppWind As IApplicationWindows
Dim pDataWind As IDataWindow
Dim pDataWindows As ISet
pAppWind = pApplication
pDataWindows = pAppWind.DataWindows
pDataWindows.Reset()
pDataWind = pDataWindows.Next()

' Loop through windows until you find the right one(s)
Do Until pDataWind Is Nothing
    If TypeOf (pDataWind) Is IMapInsetWindow Then
        '' this is the one! it's a Map Inset Window
        Dim pInsetWindow As IMapInsetWindow = pDataWind

        For i = 0 To pMap.LayerCount - 1
            pLayer = pMap.Layer(i)
            pFSel = pLayer
            Dim pSelSet As ISelectionSet
            pSelSet = pFSel.SelectionSet
            If pSelSet.Count > 0 Then
                Dim pEnumGeom As IEnumGeometry
                Dim pEnumGeomBind As IEnumGeometryBind

                pEnumGeom = New EnumFeatureGeometry
                pEnumGeomBind = pEnumGeom
                pEnumGeomBind.BindGeometrySource(Nothing, pSelSet)

                Dim pGeomFactory As IGeometryFactory
                pGeomFactory = New GeometryEnvironment

                Dim pGeom As IGeometry
                pGeom = pGeomFactory.CreateGeometryFromEnumerator(pEnumGeom)
                Dim pEnv As IEnvelope
                pEnv = pGeom.Envelope
                pEnv.SpatialReference = pMap.SpatialReference
                pEnv.Expand(1.1, 1.1, True) ' expand by 10%

                pInsetWindow.MapInset.VisibleBounds = pEnv

                pInsetWindow.Refresh()

                Exit For ' escape out now that the zoom is refreshed
            End If
        Next
    End If
    pDataWind = pDataWindows.Next()
Loop
```